# Golang : gocraft/health package 100% CPU

Tags: go, metrics, endpoints

Im using **gocraft/health** to check the health of my service and have the metrics of each endPoint. But I have a problem:
the CPU  reach  100% after just 5 hours of starting my service I dont know why.
without using the "**gocraft/health**"  it takes just 0,7% of CPU
does anyone worked with this pack before

```
var stream = health.NewStream()

 func main() {
        // Log to stdout! (can also use WriterSink to write to a log file, Syslog, etc)
  stream.AddSink(&health.WriterSink{os.Stdout})

  http.HandleFunc("/api/getVastPlayer", vastPlayer)
  http.HandleFunc("/static/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
    })

  log.Println("Listening...")
  panic(http.ListenAndServe(":2001", nil))

  }
```

;

```
func vastPlayer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    job_1 := stream.NewJob("/api/getVastPlayer")
      //job_2 := stream.NewJob("/api/html/")
    sink := health.NewJsonPollingSink(time.Minute*5, time.Minute*5)
    stream.AddSink(sink)
        //http://creative.health.spoti.io/health
    adr:="127.0.0.1:5001"
    sink.StartServer(adr)
......
......
if bol{
job_1.Complete(health.Success)
}
else{
job_1.Complete(health.ValidationError)
}
```

Comment: Which sinks are you using (`bugsnag`, `statsd`, etc.)?  Are you using `healthd`?

Comment: Have you tried to profile the process to see what's using the CPU?

Comment: Disclaimer: haven't ever used this library, but did check out the source code. Do you remove the Sink you add in the vastPlayer handler on every incoming http request? The "stream" object seems to iterate over all the Sink instances and it appears you add a sink on every request.

Comment: @ChrisB.  Great, didnt notice it, I put the **Sink** in the main function and it works pefectly now,Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's right code:

```
var stream = health.NewStream()

 func main() {
        // Log to stdout! (can also use WriterSink to write to a log file, Syslog, etc)
  stream.AddSink(&health.WriterSink{os.Stdout})


   sink := health.NewJsonPollingSink(time.Minute*5, time.Minute*5)
    stream.AddSink(sink)
        //http://creative.health.spoti.io/health
    adr:="127.0.0.1:5001"
    sink.StartServer(adr)

  http.HandleFunc("/api/getVastPlayer", vastPlayer)
  http.HandleFunc("/static/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
    })

  log.Println("Listening...")
  panic(http.ListenAndServe(":2001", nil))

  }


  func vastPlayer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    job_1 := stream.NewJob("/api/getVastPlayer")
      //job_2 := stream.NewJob("/api/html/")


......
......
if bol{
job_1.Complete(health.Success)
}
else{
job_1.Complete(health.ValidationError)
}

}
```

PS:
https://github.com/gocraft/health#jobs